# elasticsearch and not_analyzed - STIll cant find stuff

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapped entity like this:

```
{ "Organisation":{
  "properties":{
     "_abstract_":{
        "type":"string",
        "store":"yes"
     },
     "_author_":{
        "type":"string",
        "store":"yes"
     },
     "_editdate_":{
        "type":"date",
        "index":"analyzed",
        "store":"yes",
        "format":"dateOptionalTime"
     },
     "_id_":{
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed",
        "store":"yes",
        "omit_norms":true,
        "index_options":"docs"
     },
     "_title_":{
        "type":"string",
        "store":"yes"
     },
     "country":{
        "type":"string",
        "store":"yes"
     },
     "countrycode":{
        "type":"string",
        "index":"not_analyzed",
        "omit_norms":true,
        "index_options":"docs"
     },
     "creationdateutc":{
        "type":"date",
        "index":"analyzed",
        "store":"yes",
        "format":"dateOptionalTime"
     }, ...
```

CountryCode can have values like CNTRY/US.  I cannot query this - it still wants to split the value into two tokens even though it's not_analyzed. eg:

```
{ "query":{
  "bool":{
     "must":[
        {
           "term":{
              "countrycode":"cntry/us"
           }
        }
     ],
     "must_not":[

     ],
     "should":[

     ]
  }},   "from":0,   "size":50}
```

I dont get it.  Am I misunderstanding something simple?

Comment: Could you post a complete repro of this issue?

Comment: There's a lot of code so no, not really.  I was hoping someone has had the same problem and solved it.  I think it's something to do with the analyzer used when indexing and searching.  I've been playing with these but now it seems to return wrong results rather than no results.  Sigh... I need beer...

Comment: Sometimes, trying to create a small repro helps to solve the issue. I can think of several reasons why this issue is occurring. Unfortunately, I don't see enough information in your question to answer it with any level of certainty. I can only guess what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by specifying the search AND index analyzer as 'keyword' in the field mapping.

I also compounded my problems by using the wrong case for the values I was searching for (when keyword, the values are not lowered) and when using Head I was GETting the query instead of POSTing it.  Doh!

Thanks